# imacros: Identify dynamic frame # containing a given button

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros

FF 42.0 Imacros for FF BUILD=8940826 Early 2008 8 core MacPro OSX 10.8.2

edited to implement suggestion given, and changed to a function since I need to use a version of this several times.

This function will find the appropriate frame IF the button info matches.

```
function SearchFrame()
{

var check =  "CODE:";
check =  "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0";
check+=  "FRAME F={{i}}" + "\n"; 
check+=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=DATA-LOG-CLICK:add-button&&DATA-TOOLTIP-REMOVE:Unfollow&&DATA-TOOLTIP-ADD:Follow&&DATA-TOOLTIP:Follow&&CLASS:button<SP>button-icon-only<SP>button-add<SP>mo-add&&DATA-BUTTON:add&&TYPE:button&&ARIA-LABEL:Follow&&TXT:" + "\n"; 

frame=1;

for(i=1;i<=25;i++){
iimSet("i",i)

//if the result of the macro is true save frame number and break
if(iimPlay(check)==true)
{

frame=i;
break;
}
}
//return frame number
return frame;


}

SearchFrame()
```

So, after running this a number of times, I noticed that there were small changes in the button info when I recorded the press on multiple occasions.  For instance, some times it says ...button-icon-onlybutton-add... and sometimes it changes the order to ...button-addbutton-icon-only...

So, I tried experimental mode as advised, it yields this for button press:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#overview>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>BUTTON" BUTTON=0
```

Tried squeezing that whole line in between quotes where the other info is currently (except adding \ to escape inner quotes) to yield:

```
check+=  "EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=\"#overview>DIV:nth-of-type(3)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV:nth-of-type(2)>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>DIV>BUTTON\" BUTTON=0" + "\n";
```

Just cycles through and doesn't find match for button.

Or... can I maybe get around this by implementing a wildcard to account for the variations?  Several attempts not working so far.  Not clear if I need to excape * as well since it's within quoted string.

Comment: (1) I believe that there’s a problem about the button info. Try to record this line in ‘Experimental event recording mode’. (BTW, you don’t need the command `iimPlay(“pressButton”)` because the line mentioned above does that.) (2) Set `var playlistFrame = 1;` , as ‘iMacros’ keeps count from 1 (not 0). (3) Add the command `SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0` after `TAB T=1` in order not to waste 6 seconds for waiting tags.

Comment: thx.  Changed question to reflect suggestions, and now have single isolated issue of button info being dynamic (as well as now fixed issue of frame # being dynamic) per page load.  Unable to utilize returned info thus far from experimental mode.

Comment: After lots more experiments, I've found that even using this in another part of the site where the tag doesn't change, adding a line that changes the timeout of either the tag, the step, or the page causes it to cycle through instantly and fail to find anything.  Eliminating the line makes it work, but with 6 second delay in between.  I have triple checked syntax.  I can't find any reason for this happening.  Conflict with global settings?  I was under impression local definition takes precidence.... but SET !TIMEOUT_STEP x with any value for x fails.  No idea why

Comment: As I understood, the issue has been already solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33586725/imacros-press-all-number-varies-buttons-within-a-given-frame) .