# imacros: Press ALL (number varies) buttons within a given frame

Tags: javascript, imacros

FF 42.0  Imacros for FF BUILD=8940826    Early 2008 8 core MacPro    OSX 10.8.2

Looking to press however many buttons happen to be present within a given frame.  I suppose I could just loop up to some unreasonably large number and ignore errors, but that seems clumsy to me.

So, if a button press for the first button in the frame looks like this:

```
TAG Pos=1 TYPE=Button ATTR=DATA-LOG-CLICK:add-button
```

and each one after that varies only by the TAG Pos#, is there a way to search for the highest TAG Pos#, then press every button up to that last one? If this is a well known item, I must just be lacking the proper search term.

Answer (score 0):

```
   // What you asked for can be done with JS.

    var macroClick;

    macroClick ="CODE:";
    macroClick +="TAG Pos=1 TYPE=Button ATTR=DATA-LOG-CLICK:add-button";

    var macroClickTest;

    macroClickTest="CODE:";
    macroClickTest +="TAG Pos=1 TYPE=Button ATTR=DATA-LOG-CLICK:add-button CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER";


    var pos=1;

    while(true)
    {

    iimSet("n",pos)
    if(iimPlay(macroClickTest)<0)
    {

    pos--;

    iimPlay(macroClick)
    }
    pos++;
    }
```